# Center a grid inside a view

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flexbox

I am creating a grid with ListView. This is my code

```
export default class CategoryContainer2 extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    this.state = {
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(['row 1', 'row 2','row 3','row 4','row 5']),
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{         
        backgroundColor:'#ebeef0',
        alignItems:'center',
        justifyContent:'center'}}>
      <ListView contentContainerStyle={styles.list}
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderRow={(rowData) => <Text style={styles.item}>{rowData}</Text>}
        />
        </View>
    );
  }
}
```

and this is the result

[image]

As you can see in my code, I am trying to center the grid in the screen, but this is not working. Do you have an idea on how to do that?

**EDIT:**

If there is only one line on the grid than the view is centered

[image]

If I increase the size of the items and the grid contains more than one line, center dose not work anymore

[image]

**EDIT:**

Here is s [snack](https://snack.expo.io/r1lUb63Tb) with the problem.

Comment: can you try adding `flex: 1` to the `View` please

Comment: I did but still not working

Comment: Can you create a [Snack](https://snack.expo.io/) with the complete example please?

Comment: add `flex:1` to Text , if doesn't work then add parent view to text with `flex:1`

Comment: I replaced <Text... by a custom component and it worked, I don't know why but it solved my problem

Comment: No, the problem is not solved :/ If there is only one line of element it works, but if there is more than one line it dose not

Comment: @bennygenel I added the snack

Comment: @user567 when I preview your snack Items are centered.

Comment: @bennygenel Not if there are more than one line of items. Try to add items in the array

Comment: if you add `justifyContent: 'center'` to the list it centers all the items but I don't know if this is the desired behavior. [Here is how it looks](https://imgur.com/a/ro5TU)

Comment: It also center the uncompleted lines which is not desired. Its supposed to be a grid

Comment: @user567 So, what is exactly what you want? To have a fixed grid with an specific amount of columns of to have any amount of objects that will wrap in a grid?

Comment: To have any amount of object that will wrap in the row, but to have the grid centered. Ty the snack with just one row of data, this is exactly what I want to achieve, but it dose not work when the grid has multipe rows

Comment: @user567 Besides adding `flex: 1` to the `View` try adding `flex: 1` to `styles.list` in `contentContainerStyle={styles.list}`. You can also try setting 'justifyContent` and `alignItems`  as `center` inside `styles.list` as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe problem is caused by `ListView` width being same as the container `View` width. I have 2 ideas on how to achieve desired behavior.

For both idea I added `paddingLeft` and `paddingRight` to container `View` to center `ListView`.

First idea is that setting `ListView` style `justifyContent: 'space-between'` or `justifyContent: 'space-around'`. This option allows to have different size of items in a row and every row will contain the most amount of item it can fit. But this option makes the second row items have different margins between items when the row is not full.

Second idea is to calculate `width` of the items and then setting up a fixed amount of items in each row. This option is more controlled but requires to fix width of the items.

I'm adding a screen of 2 different approach and [here](https://snack.expo.io/rkbFkPyCZ) is the sample app's snack

[image: screen of 2 options]